# want to verify username and password using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

```
    <script>
var emails=["umapathi@abc.com","ram@abc.com","remo@abc.com"];
var password=["ram","raheem","rober"];
var i=0;
function summit(){
var x=document.getElementById("email").value;
do
{i++;
if(x===emails[i])
{
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML="Success";
}else
{document.getElementById("show").innerHTML="Failure";
}
while(i<3)
}

</script>
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" placeholder="username or Email" id="email" required><br><br>
<input type="password" placeholder="password" id="pswd" required><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="summit()">
</form>
<p id="show">Status:</p>
```

I am trying to validate the email address just using javascript. Is it even possible. Please correct my code I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: What error(s) are you receiving?

Comment: You realise how  easy this will be to hack, right? Anyone can see/download your javascript

Comment: Thank you for your support and effort. I know the risk involved in it. But I am not posting it on website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop on the email and password array. For example:

```
var correct = false;
for (int i = 0; i <= emailArray.length; i++)
{
  if (emailTextBoxValue != emailArray[i])
  {
    //the email at [i] isn't valid
  }
  else
  {
    if (passwordTextBoxValue == passwordArray[i])
    {
      correct = true;
    }
    else
    {
      //the password at [i] isn't valid
    }
  }
}
if (!correct)
{
//Credentials are wrong
}
else
{
//Credentials are right
}
```

Just a quick warning, this will be the most insecure system possible. If someone opens developer tools, they can instantly see your credentials

Comment: read the code, his intentions are not what you think, though they are poorly communicated

Comment: @RhysO and Yoda thank you for answering this kind of question that no one asked it before. Though it may appear silly, just wanted to know how it will look like.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad idea to do that using javascript.
All javascript vars are available for everyone opening his debug tool(F12).

Because you send your emails and passwords into an array, everyone could hack your system (Simply).

You had to check the login/password server side.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I understand risk involved in it. So kind of you.